# How to wait until a directory exists in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I would like to pause my ansible playbook until a certain directory exists.
I am aware that I can check if a file exists or not with

```yaml
    - name: Wait until the file /home/myfile.txt is present before continuing
      wait_for:
        path: /home/myfile.txt
        state: present
```

but this doesn't seem to work for directories.

I also know that I can check for a directory with this sample code

```yaml
    # Determine if a path exists and is a directory.  Note that we need to test
    # both that p.stat.isdir actually exists, and also that it's set to true.
    - name: Get stats of the FS object
      ansible.builtin.stat:
        path: /path/to/something
      register: p
    - name: Print a debug message
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Path exists and is a directory"
      when: p.stat.isdir is defined and p.stat.isdir
```

is it possible to combine both approaches?

Comment: Is it failing for you when checking with `wait_for` for directories? What version of Ansible are you using? What error message you are receiving? This issue was [solved](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20870) in 2017

Comment: Ansible 2.4+ has the fix for checks of linux directories

Comment: [`but this doesn't seem to work for directories.` is not an accurate description of your problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Wait for trigger directory
    ansible.builtin.wait_for:
      path: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/trigger/"
      state: present
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result
```

running

```yaml
TASK [Wait for trigger directory] *********************************************
ok: [test.example.com]
Thursday 02 March 2023  09:09:25 +0100 (0:00:08.185)       0:00:08.223 ********
```

and after creation of an directory called `trigger` on the Remote Node

```bash
user@test:~$ pwd
/home/user
user@test:~$ mkdir trigger
```

will result into the correct expected behavior of

```yaml
TASK [Show result] ************************************************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  result:
    changed: false
    elapsed: 7
    failed: false
    gid: 1234567890
    group: ansible_users
    match_groupdict: {}
    match_groups: []
    mode: '0755'
    owner: user
    path: /home/user/trigger/
    port: null
    search_regex: null
    secontext: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
    size: 4096
    state: directory
    uid: 123456789

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
test.example.com : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0 ...

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 8 seconds
Thursday 02 March 2023  09:09:25 +0100 (0:00:00.107)       0:00:08.330 *********
================================================================================
Wait for trigger directory ----------------------------------------------- 8.19s
Show result -------------------------------------------------------------- 0.11s
```

**Further Documentation**

- [`wait_for` module – Waits for a condition before continuing - Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html#return-values)

  > ***`elapsed`** The number of seconds that elapsed while waiting*